# Head-on collision between electron and proton?

Tags: special-relativity, energy, electrons, collision, protons

There was head-on collision between electron with 60 GeV and proton with 800 GeV.

When considering relativity, how can calculate center of mass frame energy after collision?

Answer (score 2):

This is where 4 vectors come in handy. With $p_{\mu}$ ($k_{\mu}$) representing the proton (electron) 4-momenta:

$$p_{\mu} = \big(E_p, 0, 0, \sqrt{E_p^2-M_P^2}\big) \approx
E_p\big(1, 0, 0, 1-\frac 1 2 \frac 1 {\gamma_p^2}\big)\approx E_P(1,0,0,1)$$

$$k_{\mu} = \big(E_e, 0, 0, -\sqrt{E_e^2-m_e^2}\big) \approx
E_p\big(1, 0, 0, 1-\frac 1 2 \frac 1 {\gamma_e^2}\big)\approx E_e(1,0,0,-1)$$

So add those up to get the variable $s$ (see: Stanley Mandelstam):

$$ s = (p_{\mu} + k_{\mu})^2\approx (E_p+E_e,0,0,E_p-E_e)^2$$

$$ s = (E_p+E_e)^2 - (E_p-E_e)^2 =
4E_pE_e = 4\cdot 800\,{\rm GeV}\cdot60\,{\rm Gev}=192,000\,{\rm GeV^2}$$

so
$$
\sqrt s \approx 319\, {\rm GeV}$$

which is invariant before or after the collision.

Comment: useful link for four vectors http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Relativ/vec4.html